# C++ Thread Initialization Error: No instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc

I tried to copy the following code from https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/ to my editor:

```cpp
// thread example
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <thread>    // std::thread

void foo() {
    // do stuff...
}

void bar(int x) {
    // do stuff...
}

int main() {
    std::thread first(foo);      // spawn new thread that calls foo()
    std::thread second(bar, 0);  // spawn new thread that calls bar(0)

    std::cout << "main, foo and bar now execute concurrently...\n";

    // synchronize threads:
    first.join();   // pauses until first finishes
    second.join();  // pauses until second finishes

    std::cout << "foo and bar completed.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

but for this line

`std::thread first(foo);`

VSCode linter kept showing the error

`no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void ())`

to me. How to fix that? (This piece of code could compile using gcc but it is still annoying to see those errors)

Comment: cannot reproduce with gcc 10.2: https://godbolt.org/z/a6h8x9 Please make sure the code you are actually compiling is the code you are showing here.

Comment: Vscode is not a compiler, it sometimes fails to analyze code on the fly. Only trust error messages from an actual compiler run. Though it is annoying to have invalid red squiggles in the editor, it is the nature of the beast.